# How to Write a Python program to find smallest and largest word in a given string?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to find the **largest** and **smallest** word in a given **string**.

This is my target string.

> > 'Hello, welcome to python programming '

I have extracted the words in the string and their lengths into  key value pairs in a dictionary. Below is the code i wrote.

```
Line='Hello, welcome to python programming '

words=[x for x in Line.split()]
print(words)

lengths=[len(word) for word in words]
print(lengths)

x = {words[i]: lengths[i] for i in range(len(words))} 
print('--'*44)
print (x)
```

I am getting the resulted dictionary as below

```
['Hello,', 'welcome', 'to', 'python', 'programming']
[6, 7, 2, 6, 11]
*************************************************************************
{'Hello,': 6, 'welcome': 7, 'to': 2, 'python': 6, 'programming': 11}
```

I want to **sort** the dictionary and **print the keys** which have the **highest** and **lowest** values i.e the words which are **longest** and **shortest**.

Comment: Do you want to carry on with your current approach or would also want an alternative?

Comment: `[x for x in Line.split()]` is extremely redundant. You could expand that to `[y for y in [x for x in Line.split()]]`, or reduce it to just `Line.split()`, for exactly the same result…

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/5094841

Answer (score 2):

you could also abuse [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

line = 'Hello, welcome to python programming '
c = Counter({word: len(word) for word in line.split()})

print(c.most_common(1)[0])  # ('programming', 11)
print(c.most_common()[-1])  # ('to', 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an oneliner list comprehension, try this :

```
l = 'Hello, welcome to python programming '
print(*[i for i in l.split() if len(i) == max([len(k) for k in l.split()])]) # Gives longest word (words if multiple)
print(*[i for i in l.split() if len(i) == min([len(k) for k in l.split()])]) # Gives shortest word (words if multiple)
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
programming
to
```

If you want to go with your approach, try this :

```
x = {'Hello,': 6, 'welcome': 7, 'to': 2, 'python': 6, 'programming': 11}
sorted_x = sorted(x, key= lambda y: len(y), reverse = True)
longest_word = sorted_x[0]
shortest_word = sorted_x[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your current approach:

Using `max()` `min()`

```
maxWord = max(x, key=x.get)
minWord = min(x, key=x.get)

print("The maximum-sized word is {} with len {}".format(maxWord, x[maxWord]))
print("The minimum-sized word is {} with len {}".format(minWord, x[minWord]))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
The maximum-sized word is programming with len 11
The minimum-sized word is to with len 2
```

**Alternative**:

```
s = 'Hello, welcome to python programming '

print(max(s.split(), key=len))
print(min(s.split(), key=len))
```

**Elaborated**:

```
s = 'Hello, welcome to python programming '
maxWord = max(s.split(), key=len)
maxLen = len(maxWord)

minWord = min(s.split(), key=len)
minLen = len(minWord)

print((maxWord, maxLen))           # ('programming', 11)
print((minWord, minLen))           # ('to', 2)
```

**One-liner**:

```
print((((max(s.split(), key=len), len(maxWord)),(min(s.split(), key=len), len(maxWord)))))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
(('programming', 11), ('to', 11))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "  i love flask"
a = a.split()
b = len(a[0])
c = 0
for x in a:
    s = len(x)
    if s < b:
      b = s
    elif s > c:
      c = s 
for y in a:
  k = len(y)
  if k == b:
    print (b,y)
  elif  k == c:
    print (c,y)
```